# Batch File to Find and Replace in text file using whole word only?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script which at one point has to check in a text file and remove certain strings. So far I have this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt"
```

The only problem is that that can find and replace but will not remove the line all together.

The second problem is that say I am removing the line that has `Mark`, it needs to not remove a line that has something like `Markus`.

I don't know if this is possible with the powershell interface?

Comment: Be more specific by adding what you've tried and what should be the result you're expecting. [ask]

Comment: IIRC -replace is regex enabled so you want to search for `\bMark\b` to match mark surrounded by word boundaries, i.e. a whole word match.

Comment: Subject line mentions batch, but question is actually about Powershell..

Comment: The issue is, by doing this it would be a different type of improper question. I would be asking how to make my solution work instead of asking about my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code will only replace `foo` with `bar`, this is what `replace` does.

Removing the whole line if it matches requires a different approach, almost backwards, as you can use `notmatch` to output any lines that do not match you filter - effectively removing them.

Also using regex [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) will then only match `Mark` but not `Markus`:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "\bMark\b"} | Set-Content file.txt
```

Comment: Genious! Thank You! Didn't even think of this approach!

Comment: just to be clear, this will not leave an empty line, it will remove the line altogether right? Cant test it at the moment.