# Delete line if it includes a specific string

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a text file where it will say the computer name and current date they logged in.

```
04/10/2017,  "PC1"
04/10/2017,  "PC4"
05/10/2017,  "PC3"
09/10/2017,  "PC2"
```

I'm having issues trying to run a script that will look for any line that includes *"PC2"* and delete that line :

```
get-content "c:\file.csv" | %{if($_ -match "PC2"){$_ -replace $_, ""}} | set-content c:\file.csv
```

Comment: While you have answers and it is pretty obvious what your issues are it is always helpful to explain  what _I'm having issues_ means. Knowing your desired result is always appreciated as to not waste anyones time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File to Find and Replace in text file using whole word only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179991/batch-file-to-find-and-replace-in-text-file-using-whole-word-only)

Answer (score 4):

```
(Get-Content 'C:\File.csv') -notmatch 'PC2' | Set-Content 'C:\File1.csv'
```

You can also use regex

File extension is csv

```
Import-Csv 'C:\File.csv' -Header Logged,Computer | 
       where {$_.Computer -ne 'PC2'} |
              Export-Csv 'C:\File.csv' -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Huh.  I didn't know you could use comparison operators like that (without `?`).  I guess it works because you're comparing to a string array.

Comment: Export-CSV will fuddle the output by adding quotes that were not already there but it is a solution nonetheless.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, the question mark is an alias for `Where-Object` or `where`.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard I'm well aware.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\File.csv') |
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*PC2*' } |
    Set-Content -Path 'C:\File.csv'
```

Here you go.  This utilizes an easier-to-understand wildcard comparison operator and just filters out the lines that have the matched string.